# Open Source OAuth2 Solutions for Native Clients?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

I have a cross-platform native client (Windows, macOS, Linux) and I would like it to access a web API protected by OAuth2. According to [OAuth 2.0 for Native Apps](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8252) the native client must perform the following steps:

> (1)  The client app opens a browser tab with the authorization
> request.
>
> (2)  Authorization endpoint receives the authorization request,
> authenticates the user and obtains authorization.
> Authenticating the user may involve chaining to other
> authentication systems.
>
> (3)  Authorization server issues an authorization code to the
> redirect URI.
>
> (4)  Client receives the authorization code from the redirect URI.
>
> (5)  Client app presents the authorization code at the token
> endpoint.
>
> (6)  Token endpoint validates the authorization code and issues the
> tokens requested.

A lot of these steps are very platform specific. For example, (1) "open a browser tab" and (4) "receive the authorization code from the redirect URI". Before I reinvent the wheel I am seeking an open source solution that already solves these problems in a cross-platform way.

**EDIT**: The linked RFC cites [AppAuth](https://appauth.io).

**EDIT**: I put together my own solution at https://github.com/billziss-gh/oauth2-helper that runs on Windows, Cygwin, macOS, Linux (MIT license).

Comment: Any specific language you use ? Because library will depend on your language

Comment: I am using Go for this project. I could interface with C or other native library. A standalone helper executable that accepts a URI/args and spits out the authorization code/token in stdout is also a possibility and could be developed in any language (and likely how I will approach this, if I have to develop a solution myself).